# What does "NoSuchMethodError" mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, jena

I still stuck with my text search with Jena and Lucene. It got some errors after i compiled it and after i fix one error, it always show up another error. My full codes like below:

```
public class JenaTextSearch {

static {LogCtl.setLog4j();
    BasicConfigurator.configure();}
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("JenaTextSearch");



public static void main (String ...argv)
{
    Dataset ds = createCode();
    //loadData(ds, "data.ttl");
    queryData(ds);

}

public static Dataset createCode()
{
    //base data
    Dataset ds1 = DatasetFactory.create();
    Model defaultModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    defaultModel.read("to_index/data.ttl", "N-TRIPLES");
    ds1.setDefaultModel(defaultModel);


    //define the index mapping
    EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition ("uri", "text", ResourceFactory.createProperty(App.URI_PREFIX,"content"));

    Directory dir = null;

    try {
        dir = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get("index")); //lucene index directory
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //join together into a dataset
    Dataset ds = TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(ds1, dir, new TextIndexConfig(entDef));

    return ds1;

}

public static void queryData(Dataset dataset)
{
    String prefix = "PREFIX email: <" + App.URI_PREFIX+">" +
            "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>";

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'good'");
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE " +
            "{ ?s text:query (email:content 'good'." +
            " ?s email:content ?text . " +
            " }" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    }finally { dataset.end();}
    long finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    double time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println ("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms", time));

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'bad'");
    query = "SELECT * WHERE" +
            "{ (?s ?score ?lit) text:query (email:content 'bad' \"highlight:s:<em class='hiLite'> | e:</em>\") ." +
            " ?s email:content ?text . " +
            " }" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);

    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    } finally { dataset.end() ; }
    finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms",  time));
}}
```

The error description after i last compiled shows: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper: method <init>()V not found`.

what does "NoSuchMethodError" mean? do i skip one library of Lucene? please advise me. thank you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html

Comment: you compiled with one version, where that method `<init>()V` existed (it is a no-arg constructor, actually), but executed with another version, without that method.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov thanks for explaining. so, what should i change?

Comment: Generally, you should use the same  version of the class `AnalyzerWrapper` both at compile time and at run time. Specifically, you are using old version at compile time which has deprecated no-arg constructor. Change it to newer version, and use constructor with argument: `AnalyzerWrapper(Analyzer.ReuseStrategy reuseStrategy)`.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov If the default constructor is only used within a dependency, the error could also be due to incompatible dependencies and not causing a compile error, but only visible as exception at run time.

Comment: @howlger yes, and the full stack trace needed to make exact diagnose.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Do you like to answer the question by just mentioning both cases (incompatible dependencies or `new AnalyzerWrapper()` in the code with different dependencies at run time vs. at compile time)?

Answer (score 1):

The absent method is `AnalyzerWrapper#<init>()V`, that is, a no-arg constructor of the class `org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper`. It existed in early versions of the `lucene-core` library, then it was deprecated and finally deleted.

You run your application with recent version of the library, but some part(s) of your application was compiled against an old version (where the no-arg constructor existed). This can be your code, or some third-party library.

You can look at the stack trace to determine which part of your application calls the no-arg constructor and so needs to be refactored and recompiled or replaced with more recent version.